# Initialize object with type [key, value: Array] in shorthand form

Tags: javascript

Suppose I want to loop through an array of characters and build up an object which represents the frequency of each character, for example:

```
const frequency = {};
const str = 'stackoverflow';

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    frequency[str[i]] = (frequency[str[i]] + 1) || 1;
}
```

With the above, we would expect an object in the form of:

```
{
    s: 1,
    t: 1,
    a: 1,
    c: 1,
    k: 1,
    o: 2,
    v: 1,
    e: 1,
    r: 1,
    f: 1,
    l: 1,
    w: 1
}
```

Now suppose I wanted to loop through an array of nested arrays, each with a form of `[id, val]`. Can I create an object such that I would end up with multiple keys, each representing a different `id`, and a corresponding array, filled with the `val`ues, in the same shorthand form as above?

For example:

`[ [1,2], [1,3], [1,5], [2,7], [3,0], [1,10] ]`

```
{
    1: [2,3,5,10],
    2: [7],
    3: [0]
}
```

Is there something similar to:

```
const map = {};

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    map[list[i][0]] = (map[list[i][0].push(map[list[i][1])) || [list[i][1]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Functional approach with `.reduce()`:

```js
const list = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,5],[2,7],[3,0],[1,10]]
const x = list.reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a[k] = [...a[k] || [], v], a), {})
console.log(x)
```

Edit: stole @jered's much better conditional instead of ternary

Answer (score 1):

Classic use case for a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const arr = [ [1,2], [1,3], [1,5], [2,7], [3,0], [1,10] ];
const map = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [cur[0]]: [...(acc[cur[0]] || []), cur[1]]
  };
}, {});
```

Of course, it could be a lot more readable than this... but [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) make it pretty slick and compact (it'd fit on a single line if you wanted to).

Edit: ooo I like @woat's use of single character var names and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the function signature :) We could throw that in too:

```
const arr = [ [1,2], [1,3], [1,5], [2,7], [3,0], [1,10] ];
const map = arr.reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({...a, [k]: [...(a[k] || []), v]}), {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const list = [ [1,2], [1,3], [1,5], [2,7], [3,0], [1,10] ];
const map = {};
for (let item of list) {
  map[item[0]] = [...map[item[0]] || [], item[1]];
}
console.log(map);
```